# Generate value for a property in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I want to generate a unique guid/uuid value for a property which is not a primary key in hibernate. In other words, I want to generate values for an alternate primary key.

How can I do this using Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way might be to just treat this alternate key like every other "normal" property of your pojo. Whenever you create a new instance of an object you just something like

```
myinstance.setAlternateKey(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

If your want hibernate to automatically create a new UUID when saving a new object to the database, then you could do this by using hibernate's [interceptors and event listeners](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/events.html), especially the PreInsertEventListener.